# sound transition with reveal.js

Tags: reveal.js

I'm learning to use reveal.js and I find it very powerful.
I wonder wether it's possible to make reveal play a sound at each slide transition.
I made a presentation with the auto-sliding option on and it would be usefull to have a sound when the slide changes.
Can someone help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `data-autoplay` attribute for this, it works for both video and audio elements. When this attribute is present on a media element inside of reveal.js that element will play/pause automatically as you enter/leave the slide it lives in.

```
<section>
  <audio data-autoplay src="yourAudioFile.mp3"></audio>
</section>
```

https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#embedded-media

Comment: Thank you.It works perfectly with Chromium Browser but not in Firefox ? Why ?